# IE11 Script1003 expected :

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, internet-explorer-11, babeljs

I am trying to add support for IE11. I get the errors:

> SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'
>
> File: vendor.bundle.js, Line: 8699, Column: 8
>
> SCRIPT5009: 'webpackJsonp' is undefined
>
> File: app.bundle.js, Line: 1, Column: 1

Line 8699 throws at this:

```
style(props, propName, componentName) {
  if (props[propName] == null) {
    return undefined;
}
```

It seems as though babel isn't transpiling this [Object Initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_6) to `style: (props, propName, componentName)`.

package.json:

```
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
"babel-eslint": "^8.2.2",
"babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
"babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.4",
"babel-plugin-relay": "^1.4.1",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
"babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
"babel-register": "^6.18.0",
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "stage-2",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "relay"
  ],
}
```

webpack.js:

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  include: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/components'),
  ],
  loader: 'babel-loader',
},
```

I presume the second error is being caused by the first.

Edit:

Full error code:

```
var _StyleValidator = __webpack_require__(1396);

var _StyleValidator2 = _interopRequireDefault(_StyleValidator);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

var styleValidator = exports.styleValidator = new _StyleValidator2.default();

function configStyleValidator(config) {
  styleValidator.setConfig(config);
}

exports.default = {
  style(props, propName, componentName) {
    if (props[propName] == null) {
      return undefined;
    }

    for (var _len = arguments.length, rest = Array(_len > 3 ? _len - 3 : 0), _key = 3; _key < _len; _key++) {
      rest[_key - 3] = arguments[_key];
    }

    var objErr = _propTypes2.default.object.apply(_propTypes2.default, [props, propName, componentName].concat(rest));
    if (objErr) {
      return objErr;
    }
    return styleValidator.validate(props[propName], componentName);
  }
};
```

Comment: `style: (props, propName, componentName)` That doesn't make any sense either, to me it looks like the `style` should be prefixed with `function` to make it logical JS.  I think were missing something else here, what comes before that `style` bit..  say on line 8698?

Comment: @Keith I added the full relevant code before and after it.

Comment: Ah right, that sort of function declaration didn't come out till "ES2015", so you will want to add the `ES2015` babel preset to make work on IE11.

Comment: @Keith I thought babel-env was a replacement for this?

Comment: Yes, indeed.  `env` preset should do it, so I wonder if there is another `.babelrc` been used that's not got this.  Maybe one of your lib's your using doesn't have this set.  If this is the case using webpack you can override the `.babelrc` settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a package import that targets node instead of the browser, in my case it was react-html-email: https://github.com/chromakode/react-html-email/issues/51